# Model object being re-instantiated. Possibly by IoC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, abstract-class, ioc-container

I have a View that uses RenderAction to render another View - it used to all work fine, but I did a reasonably small refactoring and moved some of my Model's properties to an abstract base class (which my model inherits).

```
Html.RenderAction("MyAction","MyController", Model);
```

If I put a breakpoint here, I can see my model object fully populated, however when step further into it my Model seems to be re-instantiated - with all properties not being set and therefore I am getting a lot of Null Reference exceptions.

RenderAction causes my IoC container (Castle Windsor) to instantiate a new instance of MyController. Is it also instantiating my Model object for some reason?

To further complicate things, when VS shows me my exception it essentially says "Property X is null" but when I look at QuickWatch the property it is not null.

I thought I might have had an wrong understanding of abstract classes but if I change the base to a normal class I get the same result.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 1.0.

Edit:

Also MyAction returns an ActionResult - if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Mauricio - I am not. I'm configuring with XML - its pretty standard and it is working for many other dependencies (all interfaces, no abstracts).

Comment: This looks like a misunderstanding of RenderAction.

Comment: And no, Windsor won't instantiate things that you didn't register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RenderAction's object parameter is for route values, not the model. You'll need to create the model yourself in the MyAction method.

Comment: thanks. I knew it was something silly. Funny enough, passing the model used to work - I better go looking through the rest of the code - make sure this isnt everywhere!